# Remove select all from library view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I remove the check box select all in a library view?
I'm using SP2010 Enterprise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps will help you remove the checkbox:

[image]

Uncheck the option "Allow individual item checkboxes"